# No done button to cancel search in MPMediaPickerController - iOS 11 beta iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios11

My code,

```
let mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: MPMediaType.music)
mediaPicker.delegate = self
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
mediaPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet
self.present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How to reproduce,

1. Execute the above code to open the picker
2. Tap on the search bar

There is no way to cancel the search without typing a search term and selecting an item. Works fine in the iPhone.

iPhone,

[image: MPMediaPickerController search with done button in iPhone]

iPad,

[image: MPMediaPickerController search without the done button in iPad]

Notice the missing 'Done' button. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: change this `mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true` and try once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, tried. No luck.